# Using wildcards to match a directory in bash

Tags: bash, directory, wildcards

Lets say the folder structure is like so:

```
/home/
--user1/asdf
--user2/asdf1234
--user3/asdf325234
--cool/asdf
```

How could I change to asdf1234 without specifying the user? For example:

```
cd /home/*/asdf1234
```

How can I use "not" in bash? For example, lets say I want to go to `/home/cool` but use not capability:

`cd /home/!user*/asdf` is this possible?

Are these bash tricks possible?

Comment: Hm, are you in fact asking two questions? The first question works as you describe it (if permissions are OK), with the `*` wildcard. **Not** in bash may look like `!` or `^`; check out `man bash` and search for those. Last, please make an effort to write better titles to your future questions.

Comment: Your two questions may be related in terms of a problem you're trying to solve (in which case, ask about that problem), but if you think about it from a web search point of view for someone trying to answer one of those two, they're different questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turn on the `extglob` shell option and then `cd /home/!(user*)/asdf`

Comment: See also: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/889746/394041) which describes `extglob` in more detail and the accompanying [question](https://askubuntu.com/q/889744/394041) which shows how to set the shell option.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command to change to asdf1234 directory without specifying the username:

```
cd $(find . -name asdf1234 -type d | sed 1q)
```

`sed 1q` ensures that only one directory name is passed as argument to `cd`.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for using `sed 1q` instead of `head -n1`?

Comment: @poige: i like sed and awk :) no other reason.